# vi/vim alternative to sublimetext's "Expand selection to scope"

Tags: vim, text-editors, sublime-text-2, vi

Sublime text has a cool feature called "*Expand selection to scope*" *SHIFT+CMD+SPACE* which selects the everything within the scope.

It select everything in scope, works perfectly ( ) or [ ] or { } repeating it expands the scope to its parent.

I'm looking to achieve the same with vim.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you meant `vim` you can do this with visual-mode (`:help visual-mode`) and text-objects (`:help text-objects`).

To select a curly-braced block do: <kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>, to select the enclosing block repeat <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>. Note that you can choose to only select the contents of the braces by using <kbd>i</kbd> instead of <kbd>a</kbd>.

These commands, as many others in vim, are built up by an action followed by a text-object, where the text-object can be prepended by a number to include more objects affected by the action. So you could also delete the object by replacing <kbd>v</kbd> by <kbd>d</kbd> or correct it with <kbd>c</kbd>, etc.

There are text objects for a lot of other things besides `()`, `{}` and `[]`, e.g.:

- <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> means a word.
- <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> means a sentence.
- <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> means a paragraph.
- <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> means a `<>` block.
- <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> means a single-quoted string.
- <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> means a double-quoted string.

You may also be interested in the [surround](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) plugin which allows you to add/replace/delete surrounding characters or even tags.

Comment: Yes, I was referring vim. Thank you. is there a way to keep expanding it eg., `[[[event touchesForView: button] anyObject]` if cursor is near `touchesForView` action `v`+`a`+`[` selects `[event touchesForView: button]` I would like to expand one more level? i.e., `[[[event touchesForView: button] anyObject]`

Comment: @palaniraja: yes there is, you can prepend the text-object by a number, e.g.: `v`+`2`+`a`+`[`.

Comment: Is there an easy way to shrink the visual selection back to the previous one? E.g. if I did `v` and then `a)` thrice and want to go back to as if I had just done it two times, it's annoying to have to redo the whole sequence again. I know the `vim-expand-region` plugin mentioned in another answer has this, but I wonder if it's possible in vanilla vim.

Comment: @smheidrich: I don't know, you might want to post this as a new question.

Answer (score 8):

The [vim-expand-region plugin](http://github.com/terryma/vim-expand-region) allows to extend / shrink the visually selected region to a (configurable) set of text objects. I.e. you can start with selecting a variable, then assignment, then block, then function, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just updating this answer in 2020, hopefully someone finds this useful. If you use [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) Which I hope you use to add Intellisense in vim/neovim.

Taken from it's readme you can bind Ctrl-S to expand selection

```
" Use CTRL-S for selections ranges.
" Requires 'textDocument/selectionRange' support of LS, ex: coc-tsserver
nmap <silent> <C-s> <Plug>(coc-range-select)
xmap <silent> <C-s> <Plug>(coc-range-select)
```

So you just press `Ctrl-s` and it'll expand the selection to current scope, then invoking it repeatedly just expands one scope higher. As of writing, this only works with Typescript/JavaScript.